# "Set Value" not changing Item properly

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

Currently I have the following plan:

I have a button to download an XML, and the functions called by this button are dependant on the value of a **Select List** in the page.

Edited explanation to the Select List field: This field is supposed to be an item that will send either a "0" or "1" parameter value to a procedure. The value in it will be sent along with the user data via the download xml button, to then be able to select which part of the procedure code will be run. If the option "All" is chosen, the value of the Select List Item should be "0", while if it has the option "Partial", it should have the value "1". I imagined it would change the value of the item automatically when I change options, but I'm not 100% sure if that's how it should work. For that reason I'm using **Set Value** dynamic actions.

This is how what the Select List has as values:

```
STATIC:All;0,Partial;1
```

The problem is, the Select List value isn't being updated when I change it. I'm using a **On Change** dynamic action to write the value of the field, like this:

```
$s("P104_SEL_FIELD",1);
```

The value remains always as 0, though, as I'm using an alert DA to print out the number and verify it.

[image]

Am I missing something with the **Set Value** function? I tried just using the APEX Set Value Dynamic Action as well, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: whta is 'P104_SEL_FIELD' ?  add more details what u tried.

Comment: I changed part of the question to have a better detail of the field that I'm trying to change.

Comment: It sounds like you have an onChange dynamic action on a field to set its own value? If that's correct, why would you do that?

Comment: I was trying to "force" a value in it, because I kept trying to show the field value and always got a "null" message from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. Me trying to force a value at first was lack of experience with this particular part of the tool.

1 - I created a set of radio buttons to set the requirement of being able to choose only one of the options, "All data (0)" or "Partial data (1)".

2 - With an "onChange" dynamic action as "Set Value" to an Apex item, I was able to properly set the 0 or 1 value.

3 - Using this Apex item in an SQL Code I was able to then properly call the procedures I wanted.

I hope this helps in case someone ever has a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you don't have to bother that much.

- go to Select List's (`P104_SEL_FIELD`) properties
- under "Settings", set "page action on selection" to **submit page**

That should do it.

Comment: Doesn't really work as I expected. The page is submitted and the value selected in the Select List disappers.

What I've tried now is using a Radio Group. I managed to pass its value to a different (soon to be a Hidden field) item. The problem now is, I pass the field as a parameter to the procedure, but it doesn't seem to work. I wonder if I have to parse the field's data into number or something like that.

Comment: What is P104_SEL_FIELD's "Used" property (under the "Source" section) set to? Should be "Only when current value in session state is null".

Comment: Strange; that's a *trivial* task ... you select a value in Select List item >> push a button (it should submit the page) >> create a process which calls a procedure; its parameter is selected value; it is ran when button is pressed. Nothing fancy in that. It should just ... work! Huh.

Comment: While it didn't exactly work as I tried at first, the solution was to create a Radio Group with the values 0 and 1, and then create a Set Value dynamic action that changed a hidden field in the same page. After that, I just had to set "Submit item" in the Settings, and it worked.

Comment: OK then; I'm glad you made it! Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

With the **Set Value** Dynamic action, you shouldn't be using Javascript, like `$s()`. You should set the Set Type to "Static Value" and the Value to "1". That works for me in Apex 18.2.